# python script to update existing column values in a csv from the other csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

If I have 2 csv files as follows:

csv1.csv:

```
1,Bob,Bob@gmail.com,baseball
2,Tom,Tom@gmail.com.football
3,Bill,Bill@gmail.com,softball
...
```

csv2.csv:

```
baseball, b1
football, f1
...
```

I am looking for a Python way to replace wrong values from csv1(the third column in csv1 is equal to the first column in csv2)) by right values from csv2(the second column).

It should look like:

```
1,Bob,Bob@gmail.com,b1
2,Tom,Tom@gmail.com,f1
3,Bill,Bill@gmail.com,softball
```

My code doesn't work.

```
import csv

table1 = r'data.csv'
table2 = r'facebook_creo.csv'

creo_desc = dict()

with open(table2) as tbl2:
    t2 = csv.reader(tbl2, delimiter=',')
    next(t2) 

    for t2row in t2:
        wrong_creo = t2row[0]
        desc = t2row[1]

        creo_desc[wrong_creo] = desc

with open(table1) as tbl1:
    t1 = csv.reader(tbl1,  delimiter=',')
    for t1row in t1:
        wrong_creo = t1row[8]

    t1.writerow(t1row[8])
```

Pandas version:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv(r'data.csv')
creo = pd.read_csv(r'creo.csv')
adset = pd.read_csv(r'adset.csv')
campaign = pd.read_csv(r'campaign.csv')
CreoDict = pd.Series(creo.iloc[:,1].values,index=creo.iloc[:,0]).to_dict()
AdsetDict = pd.Series(adset.iloc[:,1].values,index=adset.iloc[:,0]).to_dict()
CampaignDict = pd.Series(adset.iloc[:,1].values,index=adset.iloc[:,0]).to_dict()
data.iloc[:,8] = data.iloc[:,8].replace(CreoDict)
data.iloc[:,6] = data.iloc[:,6].replace(AdsetDict)
data.iloc[:,4] = data.iloc[:,4].replace(CampaignDict)
data.to_csv(r'total.csv')
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, `csv2.csv` contains a translation-table for each possible value in the third column of `csv1.csv`?

Comment: @HampusLarsson yes, right. It's just a sample. In reality the first table is much bigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use pandas to read in the 2 tables, using the second table to be a dictionary of the replace values to remap into csv1.

```
import pandas as pd

# Read in the 2 csv files
csv1 = pd.read_csv('csv1.csv')
csv2 = pd.read_csv('csv2.csv')


#Create dictionary form csv2
replaceDict = pd.Series(csv2.iloc[:,1].values,index=csv2.iloc[:,0]).to_dict()

#Use dictionary to replace values                     
csv1.iloc[:,-1] = csv1.iloc[:,-1].replace(replaceDict)

# Write to file
csv1.to_csv('csv1_new.csv')
```

**Output:**

```
print (csv1)
   0     1               2         3
0  1   Bob   Bob@gmail.com  baseball
1  2   Tom   Tom@gmail.com  football
2  3  Bill  Bill@gmail.com  softball

print (csv2)
          0   1
0  baseball  b1
1  football  f1
```

Then after replace:

```
print (csv1)
   0     1               2         3
0  1   Bob   Bob@gmail.com        b1
1  2   Tom   Tom@gmail.com        f1
2  3  Bill  Bill@gmail.com  softball
```

Comment: it works. thanks alot. and one more question. if I need to update existing columns values in a csv from 3 or 5 other csv docs.the steps should be the same?

Comment: yes, the concept/steps are the same. What I would probably do is combine all those "reference" csvs into 1 dictionary initially, then apply it to csv1 one time.

Comment: even if i need to replace values in different columns?

Comment: youd have to adjust `.iloc[:,-1]` in the code to reflect the columns you want. Is it possible that you can edit your orginal question to provide the additional scenario and I can show you/adjust my solution?

Comment: thank you. it would be great. I've added another version in my question.

Comment: @Juliya, I don't see an issue with your code. Does it not work? Would it be possible to email me? Including those 4 csvs? jason.schvach@gmail.com

Comment: It works. I just thought, that it's not optimal and I need to short it someway. Nevertheless, thank you alot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv

table1 = r'a.csv'
table2 = r'b.csv'

creo_desc = dict()

with open(table2) as tbl2:
  t2 = csv.reader(tbl2, delimiter=',')
  for t2row in t2:
    creo_desc[t2row[0]] = t2row[1]

print(creo_desc)

ans = []
with open(table1,'r') as tbl1:
  t1 = csv.reader(tbl1,  delimiter=',')
  for t1row in t1:
    if t1row[-1] in creo_desc:
      t1row[-1] = creo_desc[t1row[-1]]
    ans.append(t1row)

with open(table1,'w') as tbl1:
  writer = csv.writer(tbl1)
  writer.writerows(ans)
```

1) a.csv

```
1,Bob,Bob@gmail.com,baseball
2,Tom,Tom@gmail.com.football
3,Bill,Bill@gmail.com,softball
```

2) b.csv

```
baseball, b1
football, f1
```

Answer (score 0):

It would have been better if you would enclosed the error message, however, I guess you should use `csv.writer` where you would like to make changes rather than `csv.reader`..